# Change trace order in parallel plots with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a question about plotly parallel_coordinates function.

To reproduce my case use this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

np.random.seed(100)
data = np.random.random([1000,2])
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["data1","data2"])
fig_parallel = px.parallel_coordinates(data_df,
                                       color="data2",
                                       dimensions=["data1","data2"])
fig_parallel.write_html('test.html')
```

You will get this image: [image]

The color-bar correspond to the last axis ( data2).

We can notice that the traces going to the top of the last axis (the yellow ones) are in front of the plot.

What I want to have is the same plot but with the **blue traces in the front** of the image to have a better visualisation (bottom data are my data of interest).

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me a solution ^^

Comment: Hey @WinterGrim, it would be useful if you could provide a sample data set (it can be a small subset of your data) and enough code to reproduce the graph. As your question stands, one can only answer if they have experienced this particular problem before.

Comment: How about reversing the list of colors? Would that solve your problem?

Comment: I used this command line but it does not work ( I also tried with  with 'parcoord' in the selector and no change). 
`fig.update_traces(line_reversescale=True, selector=dict(type='parallel_coordinates'))`

Comment: @BeniTrainor I edited the question in order to be reproducible. it's a random example but the question is the same.